# How to calculate Probability of "Ranking"?

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I took a course with other 10 students. After the final exam, the professor reported statistical result of scores to us:
1. The range of score: 46~98;
2. The average score: 73.3;
3 The S.D of score: 14.3;
I got 81, without any further information, how do I know the probabilities for me to be ranked in the 2nd place or the last 2nd place?

Comment: Perhaps [math.se] would be a better site for this question, unless you're specifically asking about how to answer this question with the computing software *Mathematica*?

Comment: Wrong site. Perhaps *http://math.stackexchange.com/* is what you're after...

Comment: Consider also [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com), the SE statistics and probability site.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to know the solution with the help of Mathematica.

Comment: Depending on your final objective this might be better suited for http://law.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Is this a probability course? If so, the answer is that you are in second place -- if you can figure out the answer.

Comment: Maybe I should ask a more general question concerning this topic which you won't doubt it is off topic;